# Aptana HTML Editor Shows Blank Page

Tags: html, editor, aptana

I am running Aptana as plugin in Eclipse Neon. The HTML file was created using the template at: "New From Template => HTML => HTML 4.0.1 Strict Template (*.html)".

When I click on the file in the Project Explorer a tab opens, but the file name is not it its title, and I do not see the HTML source. Here is a screen shot that includes this tab that opened a blank title:
[Tab opens without title when file clicked on.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcYbX.png)

In "Window => Preferences => General => Editors => File Associations" I have an editor named "HTML Editor (default) (locked by 'HTML' content type)" selected (appears at the top of the list). Is this the Aptana editor? Is it the correct editor?

What has gone wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also on eclipse neon, and also use the Aptana plugin, and the code editors from Aptana simply do not work with neon, so, in terms of the usefulness of Aptana with neon, YMMV.

Currently, I still use Aptana's Web perspective and App Explorer view, as I find those useful. I also use my custom theme with non-studio editors, however, for most Aptana editors, I've moved to the LiClipseText Eclipse plugin, and I can't recommend it enough. It's much more light weight, and tends to work well with a minimum of fuss.